# What allows the Wave Disk Generator to be so efficient?

Tags: waves

Researchers at Michigan State University recently invented the [Wave Disk Generator](http://www.physorg.com/news/2011-03-msu-prototype-video.html/) that is supposed to get 60% fuel efficiency. What allows it to be so much more efficient than a traditional Internal Combustion Engine?

I am aware that there is better mixing of fuel and air, but surely this alone does not produce the extreme efficiency.

Comment: Just from the fact that they are not talking about using it as a direct power system you can bet that it runs well under some constrained set of conditions, but a hybrid arrangement allows it to *always run under optimal conditions*. That's where most of the gains in a standard reciprocating-internal-combustion--electric hybrid come from, but it seems this will can do better.

Comment: That makes sense, since they are talking about developing a high-rpm generator to work with it.

Comment: @dmckee , even when running under optimal conditions a conventional gas engine will not exceed about 20, maybe 25 % . Trueborn Diesel engines achieve about 35 %

Comment: Let me just point out that rotary engines, on which this design appears to be based, have been around for a [long time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wankel_engine). Muller's et al's great innovation appears to be the addition of the serrated rows in the base of the rotors which compress the air-gas mixture more efficiently. Of course, there are probably other subtle changes that I fail to notice. Point being, Muller's engine is nice but a modification of a previous framework, not an invention per se IMHO

Comment: The better internal combustion engines are better than people think here. The Prius gasoline engine is reported to be 34% efficient. Large marine diesels can do 50%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Prof Müller said it: Shock waves in addition of the usual things.

The picture in Your link is rather different from the thing shown 
in the video, for the time being, I do not understand really what is 
the new thing. From thermodynamics it is clear, that they (hope?) 
to have a higher **effective** DeltaT, obviously without having 
higher temperatures at machiney parts (which makes them expensive and/or short-lived)

I assume that those shock waves can be transformed into working pressure 
without the high temperatures of the combustion shock wave touchng machine parts. 
I hope we will hear more  from Prof Müller in near future.

Edit:

This link is somewhat more detailed and less press-release-silly. 
in general it says what I surmised (by application of thermodynamics basics) 
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/emergingtech/wave-disk-engines-to-make-hybrid-vehicles-cheaper-more-efficient/1887

Answer (score 1):

I found a [link](http://www.greenliter.com/gas-savings/the-wave-disk-generator-a-new-fuel-efficient-engine/) that explains it nicely.